# Unstringing List of Lists

Tags: python, list

I have an empty list X = []. I am appending a bunch of list of lists into X, which contain a bunch of floats as strings. When I print X, this is what I get(for example - there are actually way more numbers and list):

```
[["['2.58', '0.35', '.754',...]\n","['2.58', '0.35', '.754',...]\n"]]
```

How do I make everything into lists and floats? So nothing will be a string?

I tried numerous for loops, but nothing worked.

Thanks.

Comment: Convert them to lists of floats before you append them to the list of list? You could also convert them afterwards but it's simpler if you do it as early as possible. So it would be helpful to know how you process "whatever" to begin with, not only what you end up with.

Comment: where is the input coming from ? consider using [pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html) instead of writing to a text file if possible.

Comment: `[map(float, eval(y.strip())) for y in X]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to get rid of the `\n` characters like so:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>>
>>> l = [["['2.58', '0.35', '.754']\n","['2.58', '0.35', '.754']\n"]]
>>> final = [[float(j) for j in i] for i in map(literal_eval,l[0])]
>>> final
[[2.58, 0.35, 0.754], [2.58, 0.35, 0.754]]
```

**Update**

If the list is like the one in the comments, then just replacing `l[0]` with `l` in the code snippet above would fix any error:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>>
>>> l = ["['2.58', '0.35', '.754']\n","['2.58', '0.35', '.754']\n"]
>>> final = [[float(j) for j in i] for i in map(literal_eval,l)]
>>> final
[[2.58, 0.35, 0.754], [2.58, 0.35, 0.754]]
```

Comment: you mean `map(literal_eval,l)` instead of `map(literal_eval,l[0])`?

Comment: ah, my bad I just saw that it is a list of list of one element.

Comment: @bulbus yes, the first time I did that mistake too :)

Comment: It says, "malformed node or string." This is the malformed node or string:    
["['2.58', '0.35', '.754']\n","['2.58', '0.35', '.754']\n"]. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Goku241 If the list is the one in your comment then just replace `l[0]` in my code snippet with `l`, this should fix it